# MultiSelectListbox style does not work using primefaces

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I got a problem with the `MultiSelectListbox` from PrimeFaces. I implemented it in my application and filled it with data. But now it displays the data very badly. As you can see in the image below my data contains long strings and the boxes did not expand. I have to add scrollbars and that doesn't look very good.

[image: screenshot]

I tried to use the `style` attribute from PrimeFaces, but I can fill in what I want, it does not change anything, even if I fill in `width:1000px`.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Neuen Eintrag hinzufügen</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:form>

    <p:multiSelectListbox value="#{eintragHinzufuegen.selection}" style="width:200%" effect="slide" header="Kategorien" showHeaders="true" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{eintragHinzufuegen.categories}" style="width:200%" />
    </p:multiSelectListbox>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" update="out" style="display:block;margin:10px 0" />

    <h:outputText id="out" value="Value: #{eintragHinzufuegen.selection}" style="display:block" />
    </h:form>
</html>
```

How to enlarge the boxes?

Comment: did u try to change it live with the developer tools of your browser? There you can see what sets the box size.

Comment: PF version? Tried using CSS?

Comment: @Kukeltje 
I am using PF 5.2. Direct CSS does not work. 

@Lule
It shows me what I put in in my xhtml


`<div id="j_id_6:j_id_7" class="ui-multiselectlistbox ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:200%">`

Comment: width:200% is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.ui-selectonelistbox, .ui-selectmanymenu,.ui-multiselectlistbox-listcontainer{
    width:200px !important;
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can add a description / explanation of your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping the `multiSelectListbox` elements in a columnar (side-by-side) layout, you are limited by the horizontal viewport space that is available. This is a limitation for both the width of the elements and their respective texts.

Firstly, you should remove the `width: 200%;` from both the `multiSelectListbox` and `selectItems` elements.

CSS, either inline, or via a stylesheet, should help.

For the `multiSelectListbox` elements, which are essentially `<select>` elements, a few styles could help with uniformity:

```
select {
  height: 100px;    /* sets a uniform height */
  overflow: scroll; /* the character length of options necessitates this,
                       unless you choose to limit the width of the options */
  width: 24%;       /* sets a uniform height */
}

option {
  font-size: 12px;  /* or smaller, if needed */
}
```

If you need these styles set inline with the HTML, you could try this (only the `style` attribute is shown, for brevity):

```
<p:multiSelectListbox style=“height: 100px; overflow:scroll; width:24%;“>
    <f:selectItems style=“font-size: 12px;” />
</p:multiSelectListbox>
```

For the headers of each `multiSelectListbox`, you can limit the height and width of the title display, if possible:

```
.header {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 20%;
}
```

I’ve created a [Codepen example to demonstrate](http://codepen.io/jacefarm/pen/gLPRxq).